# CSS multiple columns: column-span not working

Tags: css, html-table, multiple-columns

I am using CSS to split a `main` container into several columns. This works perfectly, but the `h1` element should have a colspan. It doesn't. This is my code:

HTML:

```
<main class="four col">
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </p>
</main>
```

CSS:

```
main
{
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
.col h1
{
    -moz-column-span:       all;
    -webkit-column-span:    all;
    column-span:            all;
}
.four
{
    width: 66.67%;
}
.col
{
    -moz-column-count:          2;
    -moz-column-gap:        1.5em;
    -webkit-column-count:       2;
    -webkit-column-gap:     1.5em;
    column-count:               2;
    column-gap:             1.5em;
}
```

Any idea to get this right?

Comment: Your title is confusing! are you talking about `colspan` or `column-span`?

Comment: What browser(s) are you trying it in, `column-span` is not supported in all browsers: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_column-span.asp

Comment: Please don't link to w3schools here, it is a site only useful for bare beginners and should never be used as a professional reference as it is a source of misinformation and bad coding practices. Please use a more correct source like [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/).

Comment: Use bootstrap for that purpose

Comment: `column-span`, edited that, I'm sorry to have mixed it up. I am using Safari and I know it has worked in my browser. @r3mus: I do not see the difference: I also have a container element with `column-count` and `column-gap`; and all child `h1` elements should column span all columns. My Lorem ipsum content is of course longer in reality, this is just for not messing it up.

Comment: I don't think I need a whole framework for this issue, are there alternatives?

Comment: @r3mus I'm saying it as a broader warning. While their page on column-span and/or its example may be correct (I haven't looked), they do provide a lot of bad coding practices and sometimes just completely incorrect information which, unfortunately, continues to turn beginner coders into bad coders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 2:**

The finally working example:

```
<main class="four">
  <div class="col">
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </p>
  </div>
</main>
```

Within the same CSS from the question.

---

**Update:**

`overflow: hidden; float: left;` on the css `main` style was overriding the `column-span` property. Remove them, it works.

---

Your code works fine, it's just your CSS is a bit goofy, and the `h1` should sit nested inside the classed element. Here's a working example:

**HTML**

```
<div class="newspaper">
    <h1>Heading, my glorious long heading.</h1>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius.
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.newspaper
{
    -webkit-column-count:3; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-column-count:3; /* Firefox */
    column-count:3;
}

h1 {
    -webkit-column-span: all;
    -moz-column-span: all;
    column-span: all;
}
```

Here's a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/remus/uC72x/)

Comment: But it is nested inside the `main` container, or am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe I am blind, but I really do not see the difference: I also have a container element `main` with column-count and column-gap; and all child `h1` elements should column span all columns. My Lorem ipsum content is of course longer in reality, this is just for not messing it up.

Comment: Call me crazy, but change `<main>` to `<div>` -- what happens?

Comment: Heh, sorry, my bad. Remove `overflow: hidden;` from `main` in your css. Didn't realize that it was applying to the element, not the class, so changing main to div dropped that style.

Comment: This helped me a lot. If I append these styles to `div` or to `main`, they don't work: `overflow: hidden; width: 100%; float: left;`. If I comment all of them out, it will work. If I just remove one or two of them, it won't. But I need these styles, especially the `float`. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, first, there's no need for `float: left;` -- you're column spanning, so you explicitly *do not want* it to float the next content up. If you use float, it contradicts that. Second, why do you need `overflow: hidden;`? Is it so that you can hide part of the body? In that case, place your content inside another div, set the styles on that div, and place the entire div *inside* main with the overflow set.

Comment: I want an `aside` element to appear right to the `main` container, so I need to float it. I got it working now by adding a `div` with the class `col` inside the main. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear it.

Comment: I edited your answer with my working solution to mark it as correct. But it has to be peer-reviewed still…

Comment: Approved ;) Good luck!

Comment: I like how the code snippet says `-moz-column-spam`